# how do i create/use an online user database for android app?

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse

I want to create an user database online so people can create accounts via an android app and login. How can this be realized?

Comment: Check this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: Wow, perfect! Seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I don't understand why people keep downvoting questions like this? You proved that the question was specific enough to answer it very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Your android app cannot connect directly to the database. You'll need to create a server side service layer that serves as an API between the Android app and the database. For example, if you want to get a list of all users, your app will make an HTTP GET request to

`http://example.com/api/users`

This script will query the DB for a list of all users, and respond back to the application with the data encoded as either XML, JSON or any other consumable format.

Comment: Thanks. So whenever I want to receive or send data I will call the API which will get/send the information from/to the database?
I guess the Api is on the server aswell? Where can I find information/software in order to build the api?